# report-viewer on webform looks terrible

Tags: html, object, reportviewer, rdlc, export-to-pdf

I am working on an web-application, where i need to display reports for users

issue the report looks messed up on the web but when i export it to pdf it looks like its properly formatted.

**Report View on the web:**

[image]

**When i export the same report to pdf**

[image]

I am not sure what is going on wrong, i showed it to my manager and he said it was an html error and that the box is another object that has to be contained within the table what does that mean? how do i get those table into the box? is that going to affect the pdf file created from export.

**Any Help is appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem. It has to do with the main page CSS. If you have TABLE specified anywhere in your rules, that the report table will pick it up.

I did this, which your more than welcome to try

```
 <div style="background-color: white">
                       <rsweb:ReportViewer   ID="rptViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" BorderStyle="None" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                           ShowBackButton="False" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" 
                           ShowFindControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False"
                            ShowRefreshButton="False" SizeToReportContent="True"
                            ToolBarItemBorderStyle="None" BackColor="White"
                            BorderColor="White" ShowPageNavigationControls="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowZoomControl="True" ExportContentDisposition="AlwaysInline">
                                                   </rsweb:ReportViewer>
                        </div>
```